# How do I specify a weak entity that refers to two other weak entities, which both share a fourth entity?

Tags: database, database-design, many-to-many

Question title is probably a bit cryptic, but I couldn't come up with a short version that made sense.

So I have a `Booking` table, which is a many-to-many relationship between `Customer` and `Event`. I also have an `event_activity` table, which is a many-to-many relationship between `Event` and `Activity`.

I now want a booking to be able to specify which of an activity's events it wants to take part in. So I have `booking_event_activity`, which is a many-to-many between `Booking` and `event_activity`.

Obviously `booking_event_activity` is going to need foreign keys to `Customer` and `Activity` (which will also be part of its own composite primary key), but how do I specify the final foreign key, which will be an Event's primary key? Do I make it:

1. a foreign key to Booking's Event foreign key?
2. a foreign key to event_activity's Event foreign key?
3. two foreign keys, one to each of 1. and 2.?
4. a foreign key directly to the Event table's primary key?

Comment: I think you're organizing your data incorrectly.  Your event_activity table could have its own primary key separate from the compound index of events and activities, which could be referenced by the booking table as a foreign key.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs That would work, except that this is homework, and I'm not allowed to introduce any surrogate keys. So event_activity's PK has to be a composite of its two FKs. Is that what you meant? Do you know how I resolve the original problem?

Comment: well that's ugly database design (and a bad homework problem), but in that case you're stuck using both the eventid and the activityid columns as foreign key references to the event_activity table in your booking table.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Well it's a many-to-many relationship between Booking and event_activity, so Booking can't have the two FK's you just mentioned. How about booking_event_activity could have: **1)** a FK to Booking's FK to customer, **2)** a FK to event_activity's FK to Activity, **3)** a FK to event_activity's FK to Event. But the problem then is that booking_event_activity is only referencing half of Booking's PK, because it's only referencing Event through event_activity. Hmmmm.

Comment: You can have a many-to-many relationship between multiple (2+) tables.  There's no law against that.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Oh, so you're saying dump the booking_event_activity table, and give Booking FK's to Customer, Event, and Activity? That would then mean that a customer's booking of an event will be represented by multiple rows in Booking, one for each activity they choose. But Booking also has some other data in it (fee and amountPaid), so then that data is going to be duplicated across those multiple rows. That doesn't seem right. Would you be able to add an answer, and list each table with its foreign keys, and which columns they refer to?

Comment: all right, then that's not a simple many-to-many table, and the compound foreign keys probably should not be the primary key.  That aside, in that case, I would create the `booking_event_activity` table with the columns *CustomerId*, *EventId*, and *ActivityId*, where *CustomerId* and *EventId* reference the primary key on `booking`, and *ActivityId* references `event_activity`.  There are other ways to do that too, of course.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Ah right, sorry for leaving that out. So it's not going to be a problem that booking_event_activity only has a foreign key to one of the two columns that make up event_activity's primary key?

Comment: it can be if you don't design your application well, but frankly the schema for this database is not properly organized from the beginning, so you work from where you are.  If you wanted to be more "bulletproof" you could add foreign key columns for both of the `event_activities` columns, it won't hurt anything... for myself, I wouldn't allow this design to go to production however.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I just found out that a single column can be part of multiple foreign keys, which makes the solution a lot more obvious to me. booking_event_activity will have three columns (*customerId*, *eventId*, and *activityId*), and then the two foreign keys will be (*customerId*, *eventId* on Booking) and (*activityId*, *eventId* on event_activity). So essentially what your previous comment was, except that *eventId* is referencing two tables at once, which works because it will always be the same value in those two tables. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your table `booking_event_activity` reference the columns *customerId*, *eventId*, and *activityId*.  Your *eventId* column (with SQL Server at least) can be a foreign key reference to both `event_activities` and `booking`, but take care!  Cascading relationships may not work as expected using this method.

Comment: Will keep that in mind, and also that it's not an ideal design for the real world. Thanks for all your help!